# patching thenomenclature does not work

Tags: etoolbox, nomenclature

cant really understand why, but this code does not work

```latex
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\tracingpatches
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}{\section*}{\section}{}{}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\def\nomname{Things}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}\clearpage
\section{section 1}
1 \nomenclature{a}{b} 
\section{section 2}

\printnomenclature{}

\end{document}
```

specifically the patchcmd line, the nomenclature still uses `\section*`, the log shows following

```
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.def
File: etoolbox.def 2018/08/19 v2.5f etoolbox debug messages (JAW)
)
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 15
[debug] analyzing '\thenomenclature'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ macro can be retokenized cleanly
[debug] ++ search pattern found in replacement text
[debug] ++ patching possible
[debug] == retokenizing macro now
```

whats going on here?

Comment: nobody knows what could be causing this? maybe there is another additional package needed, which is not obvious?

Comment: a college of mine has tried it on his machine, he has TeX Live 2017 installed with all packages and it works for him, so must be something with other packages or the new Version of etoolbox/nomencl has changen something.

Comment: What is the problem? The debug message says that the patch worked (`== retokenizing macro now`)...

Comment: the problem is the PDF Output, there the `\section*` is still used. But I have found that the nomencl package was changed with the new versions so thereore it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found what was causing this, ist because of the new Version of nomencl package. Going to Report it on the guthub now.